# Exporting Excel Rows As Individual XML Files

Tags: xml, excel

I don't believe Excel supports this and I've been struggling to find an add-on or program that can help. I'm trying to export individual rows (records) from a worksheet into multiple XML files. I can get Excel to export all of the rows into one XML file. This time I only need to do 100 files, so I don't mind cutting and pasting but I would really like to find an automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool mapforce from altova might help you on this.

See their helpfile and find "Multiple XML files from Excel rows"

You can install it and have a 30 day trial period I believe.